# validation errors should be in the format json as below

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

{ "status": {"code"=>-10000, "message"=>"validation error"},      "results":[],      "errors": @search_form.errors }

normally we write format.json { render json: @org.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

to get above json format how I need to write.

Answer (score 1):

Creating any JSON response is easy with a JSON template engine, for example, [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). For a detailed screencast, see [this screencast by Ryan Bates.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder)

The basic idea is to create a shared view template that would format your errors as you wish and send it back to the browser.